# Using Windows 7 Home Premium Upgrade with XP Professional

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

I have a computer with XP Professional (I assume OEM since it was installed on the computer when I bought it from Dell). If I buy a Windows 7 Home Premium Upgrade and perform a clean install, will this work coming from Windows XP Pro?

I know that I cannot perform an in-place upgrade, but I'm wondering if there is any restriction on using the XP Professional license as proof to install the Windows 7 Home Premium upgrade.

Will it be a problem that I don't have an XP Professional CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought there would be a problem as there are many people in your position and the licence terms say that you can install Windows 7 on a system with XP, just no in place upgrade.

My guess would be that you are best off starting the install from within Windows XP as that may get around any sort of check that you have a XP cd.

If this does not work, I would just do a fresh install anyway and if it fails activation, use the free phone number and tell them the situation - I am sure they will authorise it.